# overweighted Automatic Rigging Issues

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

Greeting fellow Artist. 
i'm having trouble with automatic weight rigging. the mesh is a simple humanoid character. the bone is overweighted and effecting the vertex i don't want to(like shown in image).

[image]
[image]

i know i can always manually weight paint it or re-assign the vertex group. but that defeat the purpose of "automatic" rigging don't you think??

what i wanted to ask is : is there someway so that my device can understand what i needed just by clicking the "set parent with automatic weight" without further weight painting. 
like any parameter i should change before assigning parent or any other way?

thanks in advance. sorry for bad english

Comment: try and add a neck bone, so that it will keep the arm from influencing the collar

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a normal behaviour. You can either add a bone to control the Neck part as WhovianBron3 suggested, or you manually fix it. The reason this happens is because the bone has high effect on this part of mesh because it is close enough to it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes bones influence the wrong areas of the mesh, like the arm influences the torso in your picture. Automatic weighting is fast, but sometimes not very smart. One thing you can do to help make it smarter, is to use the buttons in the Weight Tools Panel, directly after using automatic weights. In the case of your example, maybe try using "Quantize" or "Clean", with the subset set to "All Deform Pose Bones", and "Steps" set to 4. You can experiment with the number of steps, and the subset, as well as the buttons in the Weight Tools category.

1. Select mesh
2. Select armature
3. Ctrl + P > "Automatic Weights"
4. Select Mesh, go to "Weight Paint Mode"
5. Go to the "Tools" tab choose "Quantize" or "Clean"
6. Press "F6" ; Subset = "All Deform Pose Bones" ; "Steps" = 4

[image: Weight Tools Panel]

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This is exactly what i ask for i already tried and it helped so much. Thank you again :)

Comment: You are very welcome. I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can consider doing is using helper bones.  These are deforming bones that exist only to get better weights from autoweights-- after you have good weights, you can delete the bones and drop the weights to their parents, or just leave them around on some junk bone layer where the animator won't ever be bothered by them.

[image]

The selected bone, parented to the root, will suck up some of the autoweight that would otherwise go to the "arm" bone, so the armpit won't deform as much as the arm bends.